# possible to streamline stdout and stdin communication

Tags: java, python

I been learning about interprocess communication between java and python.

I am trying out some new codes but its not working as expected.

In java class

I have a method that prints

**Java**

```
public static main void (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("this is iteration 1");
    System.out.println("this is iteration 2");
    System.out.println("this is iteration 3");
    System.out.println("this is iteration 4");
}
```

**Python**

```
import sys 
while True:
    data = sys.readline()
    print "in python " + data
```

**Desired output**

```
In python : this is iteration 1
In python : this is iteration 2
In python : this is iteration 3
In python : this is iteration 4
```

**Current output**

```
In python: this is iteration 1this is iteration 2this is iteration 3this is iteration 4
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

**New problem**
However, my data = sys.stdin.readline() is not blocking. Supposedly, i do not know the number of lines my stdout would have. How would i be able to allow the stdin.readline() to be blocking after the first iteration as i cannot find a method to flush the buffer of the stdin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sys.readline()` instead of `sys.readlines()`. The former will read one line at a time, the latter reads everything available.

Comment: Thx. i guess thats what i really needed. I do have a modification to my question hopefully you can help too

Comment: Glad it helped. Re your new problem, best I think to post a new question. Suggesting showing the code your best attempt, the behavior you're getting, and the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'while' loop does not have an exit condition which causes it to execute infinitely. Instead use 'for' loop and give a range to execute exactly 4 times.

Comment: It doesnt matter how many times it executes. The output would still not be the output desired

Comment: Could you post more code so that I get better understanding and can help you with it.

Comment: Not sure if you got what i meant

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing breaking your while loop, and there is nothing creating new lines in the Python output:

```
import sys 
while True **SOME CONDITIONAL**:
 data = sys.readlines()
 print "in python " + data **+ NEW LINE**
```

Alternatively you could add a break; see [WhileLoops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop).